# Unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
x = difference.total_seconds
if difference < timedelta(minutes=60):
    minutes = int(x/60) % 60
    return "%i minutes ago" % minutes
```

Why I have

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'builtin_function_or_method' and
>   'int'

and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`total_seconds` is [a method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds), so you should call it:

```
x = difference.total_seconds()
```

Comment: For example, _this_ is a good one, because you not only fixed the typo, but also explained why it didn't work and linked to the docs. +1

Answer (score 1):

Your difference.total_seconds is a builtin_function_or_method. You may try:

```
x = difference.total_seconds()
```